# GoLang for-loop variable scope change and Table driven testing

Tags: testing, code-reviews, go

As I was reading this blog post: https://go.dev/blog/loopvar-preview about scope of loop variables and as I’m trying to learn #GoLang, I asked myself the question: “okay, but is really so common pitfall in practice?”

Then I tried it with Subtest and Table testing, ...to me becomes blatant potential pitfall:

```go
func TestHappens(t *testing.T) {
    tt := []struct {
        name  string
        lower string
        upper string
    }{
        {"test1", "a", "A"},
        {"test2", "z", "Z"},
    }
    {
        for testID, test := range tt {
            tf := func(t *testing.T) {
                t.Parallel()
                t.Logf("Test: %d name: %s for %s and %s", testID, test.name, test.lower, test.upper)

                if strings.ToUpper(test.lower) == test.upper {
                    t.Logf("Should expect %s once uppercased is %s", test.lower, test.upper)
                } else {
                    t.Errorf("Should expect %s once uppercased is %s", test.lower, test.upper)
                }
            }
            t.Run(test.name, tf)
        }
    }
    // We can notice is testing the second testtable row, twice:
    //
    // === NAME  TestHappens/test1
    //  closureforloop_test.go:21: Test: 1 name: test2 for z and Z
    //  closureforloop_test.go:24: Should expect z once uppercased is Z
    // === NAME  TestHappens/test2
    //  closureforloop_test.go:21: Test: 1 name: test2 for z and Z
    //  closureforloop_test.go:24: Should expect z once uppercased is Z
    // --- PASS: TestHappens (0.00s)
    //  --- PASS: TestHappens/test1 (0.00s)
    //  --- PASS: TestHappens/test2 (0.00s)
}
```

As you can see on on the for-loop line, I’m trying to use value semantic for-loop and apparently this would be good for the closure, except since the loop variable is not defined at an iteration scope but at the loop construct level scope, what you actually end up testing is the “last row” twice.

I was wondering if my thought-processing is correct, if anybody has hit on this on Table driven testing, and any other feedback which will help me check my reasoning on this pragmatic actualization of the problem described in the blog post, as that will help me on my quest to learn GoLang